# PHP: Remove empty values from array, then convert that to a string

Tags: php, arrays, string, implode

I know how to do each of these things separately (remove the empty values, and to convert an array to a comma-separated string) but I can't get them to work in combination, and haven't yet been able to find a good way to do so. I know I can use print_r to display the results of my filter, but that's not helpful because I eventually need to send my resulting string to a database (that's for another day). Any help is appreciated!

I have:

```
$array = array('item1', 'item2', '', 'item4');
//this should filter out the empty values (index 3)
$filter = array(array_filter($array));
//this should then take that filtered array and convert to a comma-separated string
$comma_separated = implode(",", $filter);
echo $comma_separated;
```

Every time I try this my output from that is just:

```
Array
```

Comment: You put your filtered array into another array! `array(array_filter($orderArray));` Also you should get an error, which means that you don't have error reporting turned on!

Comment: Also, $orderArray does not exist.

Comment: Just as an FYI, the return type of `array_filter` is an array. Per the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php): _"Returns the filtered array..."_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way,no need to push your after filtering to another array & where you get `$orderArray`?

```
$array = array('item1', 'item2', '', 'item4');
$filter=array_filter($array); // see here, i didn't add another array()
$comma_separated = implode(",", $filter);
echo $comma_separated;
```

**EDIT:** Shorter way to do it, **courtesy** @MHakvoort

```
  $comma_separated = implode(",", array_filter($array));
```

> array_filter: "If no callback is supplied, all entries of input equal
>   to FALSE will be removed." This means that elements with values NULL,
>   0, '0', '', FALSE, array() will be removed from it.

Comment: This can be shorter: $comma_separated = implode(",", array_filter($array));

Comment: @MHakvoort, Thanks for shorter version